# What does crypto/cipher-XORKeyStream do to the src []byte?

Tags: go, aes

I'm doing AES encryption using Go, I found that the source bytes changed after encryption. Seems that XORKeyStream function does the change if cap(source) > len(source), what it exactly does to the src []byte?

go version go1.12.5 darwin/amd64

```golang
func main() {
    byte1 := []byte("123abc")
    fmt.Println("content1:", byte1, "len1:", len(byte1), "cap1:", cap(byte1)) // content1: [49 50 51 97 98 99] len1: 6 cap1: 6
    buf := bytes.NewBuffer([]byte("123abc"))
    byte2, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(buf)
    fmt.Println("content2:", byte2, "len2:", len(byte2), "cap2:", cap(byte2)) // content2: [49 50 51 97 98 99] len2: 6 cap2: 1536

    _, _, _, err := crypt.AESEnc(byte1)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Println("content1:", byte1, "len1:", len(byte1), "cap1:", cap(byte1)) // content1: [49 50 51 97 98 99] len1: 6 cap1: 6
    _, _, _, err = crypt.AESEnc(byte2)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Println("content2:", byte2, "len2:", len(byte2), "cap2:", cap(byte2)) // content2: [132 200 7 200 195 8] len2: 6 cap2: 1536
}
```

```golang
func AESEnc(data []byte) ([]byte, []byte, string, error) {
    key := make([]byte, 16)
    iv := make([]byte, 16)
    _, err := io.ReadFull(rand.Reader, key)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, nil, "", err
    }
    _, err = io.ReadFull(rand.Reader, iv)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, nil, "", err
    }
    block, err := aes.NewCipher(key)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, nil, "", err
    }
    pdata := pckspadding(data, block.BlockSize())
    stream := cipher.NewCFBEncrypter(block, iv)
    stream.XORKeyStream(pdata, pdata)
    return key, iv, base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString(pdata), nil
}

func pckspadding(ciphertext []byte, blockSize int) []byte {
    padding := blockSize - len(ciphertext)%blockSize
    padtext := bytes.Repeat([]byte{byte(padding)}, padding)
    return append(ciphertext, padtext...)
}
```

byte2 changes after encryption, what happened?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar a crypto/cypher-XORKeyStream but I can tell you what XOR does to bits if that is helpfull.  I have some Electronic experience and here is the truth table to an XOR gate:

[image: XOR Gate Truth Table]

Inputs X and Y represent two bits. The output Z is the result of XOR-ing X and Y.

In English you would say to yourself "Inputs, either one or the other but not both" results in an output of "True".

Don't know how much help this will be or how to apply it to more than two input bits with a crypto/cypher-XORKeyStream.
But here would be an example:

```
X = 00110001010
Y = 11111111111
Z = 11001110101
```

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

It XORs each byte in the provided slice with a byte in the cipher's key stream, or as the documentation puts it:

```golang
    // XORKeyStream XORs each byte in the given slice with a byte from the
    // cipher's key stream. Dst and src must overlap entirely or not at all.
    //
    // If len(dst) < len(src), XORKeyStream should panic. It is acceptable
    // to pass a dst bigger than src, and in that case, XORKeyStream will
    // only update dst[:len(src)] and will not touch the rest of dst.
    //
    // Multiple calls to XORKeyStream behave as if the concatenation of
    // the src buffers was passed in a single run. That is, Stream
    // maintains state and does not reset at each XORKeyStream call.
    XORKeyStream(dst, src []byte)
```

This means it mutates `dst`, which is why you're observing a different input buffer after encryption is performed.